# When using Terraform with AWS, how can I set a rate limit on a specific URI path (or regex of a URI path) on an ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-waf

I am trying to rate limit requests to the forgot password change URL using WAFv2 rules attached to an ALB on Cloudfront.

What I think I need to do is..

Create two resources aws_wafv2_web_acl.afv2_rate_limit and another called aws_wafv2_regex_pattern_set.wafv2_password_url

Example of rate: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/wafv2_web_acl

Example of regex: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/wafv2_regex_pattern_set

Combine these into a rule group, call it aws_wafv2_rule_group.wafv2_rule_group_pw_rate_group

Example of group: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/wafv2_rule

I've created the rate limit and the regex, but I am failing to create the rule group. I put this rule in to refer to the rate limit

```
    rule {
        name = "rate_limit"
        priority = 1
        action {
            block {}
        }
        statement {
            and_statement {
                statement {
                    rule_group_reference_statement {  # !!FIXME!! doesn't work
                        arn = aws_wafv2_web_acl.wafv2_rate_limit.arn
                    }
                }
           }
        }
        visibility_config {
            cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false
            metric_name                = "password_url"
            sampled_requests_enabled   = false
        }
    }
```

I get the error on the rule_group_reference_statement line:

```
Blocks of type "rule_group_reference_statement" are not expected here.
```

I can attach the rule group to the ALB.

of course, the first question is whether this is even the right way to go about it?!

thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

working!

```
resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "wafv2_alb_pw5pm_acl" {
    name        = "wafv2_alb_pw5pm-acl"
    description = "prevent brute forcing password setting or changing"
    scope       = "REGIONAL"       # if using this, no need to set provider

    default_action {
        allow {}    # pass traffic until the rules trigger a block
    }

    rule {
        name     = "rate_limit_pw5pm"
        priority = 1

        action {
            block {}
        }
        statement {
            rate_based_statement {
                #limit              = 300    # 5 per sec = 300 per min
                limit              = 100     # smallest value for testing
                aggregate_key_type = "IP"

                scope_down_statement {
                    regex_pattern_set_reference_statement {
                        arn = aws_wafv2_regex_pattern_set.wafv2_password_uri.arn
                        text_transformation {
                            priority = 1
                            type     = "NONE"
                        }
                        field_to_match {
                            uri_path {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        visibility_config {
            cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
            metric_name                = "wafv2_alb_pw5pm_acl_rule_vis"
            sampled_requests_enabled   = false
        }
    }

    visibility_config {
        cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
        metric_name                = "wafv2_alb_pw5pm_acl_vis"
        sampled_requests_enabled   = false
    }

    tags = {
        managedby   = "terraform"
    }
}


resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl_association" "web_acl_association_my_lb" {
    resource_arn = aws_lb.xxxxxx.arn
    web_acl_arn  = aws_wafv2_web_acl.wafv2_alb_pw5pm_acl.arn
}
```

Comment: It's important to note that limit refers to amount of requests per 5-minutes, not 1-minute

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest a rule_group_reference_statement, for example for use inside a and_statement, not_statement or or_statement. It can only be referenced as a top-level statement within a rule.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. basically you need to declare an `aws_wafv2_regex_pattern_set`, in this example I use the URI "/api/*" but it can be a fixed one too.

```
resource "aws_wafv2_regex_pattern_set" "regex_pattern_api" {
  name  = "regex-path-api"
  scope = "REGIONAL"

  regular_expression {
    regex_string = "/api/.+"
  }
}
```

and the here is an example on how to use it on a waf declaration:

```
resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "waf" {
  name  = "waf"
  scope = "REGIONAL"

  default_action {
    allow {}
  }

  rule {
    name     = "RateLimit"
    priority = 1

    action {
      block {}
    }

    statement {

      rate_based_statement {
        aggregate_key_type = "IP"
        limit              = 100

        scope_down_statement {
          regex_pattern_set_reference_statement {
            arn = aws_wafv2_regex_pattern_set.regex_pattern_api.arn

            field_to_match {
              uri_path {}
            }
            text_transformation {
              priority = 1
              type     = "NONE"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
      metric_name                = "RateLimit"
      sampled_requests_enabled   = true
    }
  }

  visibility_config {
    cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false
    metric_name                = "waf"
    sampled_requests_enabled   = false
  }
}
```

The cool part of this is that it is a rate limit that narrows the filter based on client IP using `scope_down_statement`